# Concurrently hit URLS and process results

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I have a requirement where I need to hit up to 2000 URLs per minute and save the response to a database.  The URLS need to be hit within 5 seconds of the start of every minute (but the response can wait). Then, at the next minute, the same will happen and so on. So, it's time critical.

I've tried using Python multiprocessing and threading to solve the problem. However, some URLs may take up to 30 minutes to respond, which blocks all other URLs from being processed.

I'm also open to using something lower level such as C, but don't know where to start.

Any guidance in the right direction will help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something lighter than a thread, since if each URL can block for a long time then you'll need to send them all simultaneously instead of via a thread pool.

[`gevent`](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html) is a Python wrapper around the eventlib loop that's good at this sort of thing. From their docs:

```
>>> import gevent
>>> from gevent import socket
>>> urls = ['www.google.com', 'www.example.com', 'www.python.org']
>>> jobs = [gevent.spawn(socket.gethostbyname, url) for url in urls]
>>> gevent.joinall(jobs, timeout=2)
>>> [job.value for job in jobs]
['74.125.79.106', '208.77.188.166', '82.94.164.162']
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried out gevent and it seems to fit my use case. I'm assuming this "monkey patching" thing should patch mysql connections too, I'll give that a try also. I also found a resource that helped me: http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood the problem correctly, but if you are using 'n' processes and if all 'n' of them get stuck on a response, then changing the language will not solve your issue. Since the bottleneck is the server which you are requesting, and not your local driver code. You can eliminate this dependency by switching to an asynchronous mechanism. Do not wait for the response! Let a callback handle it for you!

EDIT: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests

Comment: I've heard of Requests before but didn't know about this library I'll take a look thanks.

Comment: It actually uses gevent internally!